# TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift

я новичок в програмировании,объясните пожалуйста как реализовать нажатие на ячейку(я делаю трекер и мне нужно создать упражнение и потом нажать на ячейку переход на следуйщее окно и там уже его редактировать, тоесть добавить количество раз,вес и тд...)помогите пожалуйста!!!

Answer (score 1):

После того как вы сделали таблицу, выделите ячейку и зажмите `Ctrl` и ведите до второго контроллера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно получиться как то так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нажмите на эту стрелочку и назначьте ей идентификатор(я сделал Segue)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код моего контроллера с `tableview`:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
    cell.name.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Segue" {
        if let cell = sender as? MainTableViewCell,
            let indexPath = tableview.indexPath(for: cell) {

            let dvc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            dvc.value = array[indexPath.row]

        }
    }
}}
```

Вот второй контроллер:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

var value = ""
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    label.text = value
}}
```

Если вы все сделали правильно, то у вас должно получится так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на ячейку 5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если возникнут вопросы, спрашивайте